# QEMU/KVM & UEFI 'unsupported configuration: smm is not available with this QEMU binary'

Tags: boot, virtualization, uefi, qemu

I have dug through the search engines before coming here out of respect for you. In other words, I try hard to figure out problems before asking someone else to do my own work for me. That said, I just can't figure this out.

I run CentOS Linux 7.7.1908 as a host but I don't think it is relevant because I had the same problem of being unable to run UEFI guests via virt-manager and QEMU under an Ubuntu host.

I have installed ovmf and can select the following option under the "Overview Tab":

> UEFIx86_64:/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.secboot.fd

I check to see that the package was properly installed and sure enough the files are there:

```
bash-4.2$ ls -l /usr/share/OVMF/
total 7144
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3653632 Aug  8 19:47 OVMF_CODE.secboot.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  540672 Aug  8 19:47 OVMF_VARS.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  540672 Aug  8 19:47 OVMF_VARS.secboot.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2578432 Aug  8 19:47 UefiShell.iso
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled OVMF several times with the same result, failure!

I keep getting this error upon attempted installation of a UEFI guest:

> Unable to complete install: 'unsupported configuration: smm is not available with this QEMU binary'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 89, in
>   cb_wrapper
>       callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 2552, in
>   _do_async_install
>       guest.start_install(meter=meter)   File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 495, in
>   start_install
>       doboot, transient)   File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 431, in
>   _create_guest
>       domain = self.conn.createXML(install_xml or final_xml, 0)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 3725, in
>   createXML
>       if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed', conn=self) libvirtError: unsupported configuration: smm is not
>   available with this QEMU binary

Very frustrating because most machines are now UEFI and I test backup and recovery software using VMs so that I don't foobar a customer's machine. I need to be able to simulate backup and recovery of various computer systems in UEFI, not just those that boot legacy BIOS/MBR. I use VMs to experiment and see if I can learn new tricks. As more BIOS machines are being phased out, I am falling behind in my skills because I cannot simulate the latest hardware anymore and cannot afford to buy tons of real hardware to use only once for experimentation.

The package "qemu" comes from the repository "epel" and the package "OVMF" comes from repository "base". I don't seem to be able to find OVMF in epel repository nor can I seem to find qemu in the the base repository so it is difficult for me to match the correct versions of each. Still, I would have thought RPM would have automatically depended the correct version of OVMF with qemu regardless of the repos used or throw an error that the dependency was of the wrong version, but that is not what I am getting. I don't understand the error, so I don't know how to fix it. I just want UEFI guests to run the same as BIOS guests and I don't understand why it has to be made so complicated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks